# Open java class at selected line and get source as String

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm creating Eclipse plugin that is listening on a socket and allows to:

- open a java class at selected line
- get the java class source code as String, InputStream or other

I have package and class name, line number and file name.

How can I open the java class in eclipse with plugin and get class source?

Comment: You can use the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801627/how-to-programmatically-find-a-java-file-in-eclipse-from-full-classname) ... though I haven't been able to get it to work for classes that are inside jar files.