# Opening an editor for a Java class that is within a jar (with source included)

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am working on [an eclipse plugin](https://github.com/eyala/pig-eclipse), and I'm trying to implement F3 (Open Declaration) functionality. After finding the project that contains a class, I use *findType* to get the IType of the class. If it a .java file in my workspace, I can use *getResource* to get the *IFile*, and then open its editor (as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801627/how-to-programmatically-find-a-java-file-in-eclipse-from-full-classname)).

However, if it's a *BinaryType*, then *getResource* returns null. I can get the class file using *getClassFile*, but when I use its *getResource* I also get null. If I try using its *getPath* method, I get an *IPath* to the jar file which contains it.

There must be some way to reach the source file, and open it in an editor, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
JavaUI.openInEditor(IJavaElement element);
```

to open all Java elements (such as your `IType`).

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "openInEditor" since that's the method I found (but it does work :-) )