# Eclipse , How to get the URI of a class

Tags: eclipse, rcp

Class<?> clazz = IWorkbench.class ;

I wonder if there is any API that can help me get the URI of class , This URI is used to open an editor

tried to make my own URL and succeeded, but I still want to use the eclipse API

```
public static IEditorPart openClassInEditorFromURI(URI uri) {
    IWorkbenchPage page = BitFanUI.getLastActivateWindow().getActivePage() ;
    if( page == null ) {
        return null ;
    }
    try {
        IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getStore( uri ) ;
        return IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(page, fileStore);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a (runtime) class doesn't have a URI.  (You can define a class on the fly from an array of bytes ...)

Having said that, most classes loaded in the normal way will have have a resource URI.  If you know the fully qualified class name and the classloader that loaded it, you should be able to do the following:

1. Transform the classes fully qualified name to its resource path.  For example "com.example.MyClass" would typically map to "/com/example/MyClass.class".
2. Use `classloader.getResource(resourcePath)` to get the URI.

However note that the URI may not be resolvable in another context.

---

I don't think that Eclipse provides an API that does the above.  (I can't find one.)

---

**UPDATE** - If you are trying to programmatically find a source URI for a class from its full name, then this might provide the answer:

- [How to programmatically find a .java file in an Eclipse plugin from full classname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801627)

Note that if you really have a `Class` object in the context of an Eclipse plugin (as implied by your `Class<?> clazz = IWorkbench.class` snippet) then you can extract the full class name from the `Class` object.  But this is sounding a bit strange ...

Comment: I think this is probably the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71178025/2670892) and they want to open the source code of an Eclipse class like the Eclipse "Open Type" dialog

Comment: It seems that I can only write an API myself :)